# Replacing a string using XSLT1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, pem

I have the folowing incoming XML input.

```
    <Cert>
    <x509Cert>-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIE7jCCA9agAwIBAgIQSxwJEMml4T/r5K/vfYKaJjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB+ MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEdMBsGA1UEChMUU3ltYW50ZWMgQ29ycG9yYXRpb24xHzAd BgNVBAsTFlN5bWFudGVjIFRydXN0IE5ldHdvcmsxLzAtBgNVBAMTJlN5bWFudGVj IENsYXNzIDMgU2VjdXJlIFNlcnZlciBDQSAtIEc0MB4XDTE1MDExMjAwMDAwMFoX DTE2MDExMzIzNTk1OVoweDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDTALBgNVBAgMBE9oaW8xETAP BgNVBAcMCENvbHVtYnVzMRcwFQYDVQQKDA5KUE1vcmdhbiBDaGFzZTEQMA4GA1UE CwwHR1RJIEdOUzEcMBoGA1UEAwwTZ25ld2ViLmpwbWNoYXNlLm5ldDCCASIwDQYJ KoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAOh5cImc6o4dXMfRtlFGZxt16FajFDi1 gZ6A4eYnuU+PUa1gxC6RF4B8ENQdW66RNVHhgatOuGQ4DuphvREnHy32NTQCNGiy xYeUwAIsLDFPY0vc0I9c/x6MoIVqJKdesnfiA41R2t41w9viS2WtXhVc9cCYOwX7 pmGYVEelUxnUUd/HUZvY5AuCUAJFzQO66BbRYjRZvJDAvE2G+xJwFaB5IJo3dU/j j ZW0H9BeIQfRDlpxb4WL0cUS70FN1RyVDPZSwnyHej+BxEN3pjZXUryBjZ8R+Z5TE zbFusEBtC8qTuT+37wUOoMLB -----END CERTIFICATE-----</x509Cert>
    </Cert>
```

I need to remove "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" (ignore case) from the string. The number of trailing and preceeding "----------" can vary.

The expected Output is :

```
    <Cert>
    <x509Cert>MIIE7jCCA9agAwIBAgIQSxwJEMml4T/r5K/vfYKaJjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB+ MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEdMBsGA1UEChMUU3ltYW50ZWMgQ29ycG9yYXRpb24xHzAd BgNVBAsTFlN5bWFudGVjIFRydXN0IE5ldHdvcmsxLzAtBgNVBAMTJlN5bWFudGVj IENsYXNzIDMgU2VjdXJlIFNlcnZlciBDQSAtIEc0MB4XDTE1MDExMjAwMDAwMFoX DTE2MDExMzIzNTk1OVoweDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDTALBgNVBAgMBE9oaW8xETAP BgNVBAcMCENvbHVtYnVzMRcwFQYDVQQKDA5KUE1vcmdhbiBDaGFzZTEQMA4GA1UE CwwHR1RJIEdOUzEcMBoGA1UEAwwTZ25ld2ViLmpwbWNoYXNlLm5ldDCCASIwDQYJ KoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAOh5cImc6o4dXMfRtlFGZxt16FajFDi1 gZ6A4eYnuU+PUa1gxC6RF4B8ENQdW66RNVHhgatOuGQ4DuphvREnHy32NTQCNGiy xYeUwAIsLDFPY0vc0I9c/x6MoIVqJKdesnfiA41R2t41w9viS2WtXhVc9cCYOwX7 pmGYVEelUxnUUd/HUZvY5AuCUAJFzQO66BbRYjRZvJDAvE2G+xJwFaB5IJo3dU/j j ZW0H9BeIQfRDlpxb4WL0cUS70FN1RyVDPZSwnyHej+BxEN3pjZXUryBjZ8R+Z5TE zbFusEBtC8qTuT+37wUOoMLB</x509Cert>
    </Cert>
```

Please advice the best way to do this.

Comment: Hi Sekhar, Welcome to S.O. Can you please provide some more information, like what you've tried so far, and what language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x509Cert">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(substring-before(translate(., '-', ''), 'END CERTIFICATE'), 'BEGIN CERTIFICATE'))" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure what exactly do you mean by "*ignore case*", though.

---

### Edit:

I have managed to locate the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468) for this type of document (a PEM file). You will see in [Section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468#section-2) that the header and footer are specified *very* precisely - down to the number of hyphens and spaces that surround the `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE` labels.

This means that for a conforming PEM file, the code can be greatly simplified to:

```
<xsl:template match="x509Cert">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 29, string-length(.) - 54)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. This works. Please help me figure out what is the proper way to search "New Line(\n)", Line break, Carriage Return and Space in a string using XSLT.

Comment: I am not expert on that, but try: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[xslt]+%22new+line%22

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look. Regarding your question on "Ignore Case", I mean that the search for "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" should be case insensitive. Is translate() the only way to achieve that in XSLT1.0 ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Are you sure you need this? It's more complicated than just plain translate, because you need to preserve the original case of the payload.

Comment: I think you are correct. In case of X.509 the "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" and "END CERTIFICATE" is always in upper case and i think that's the case for all X509 certificate. So, the solution you provided will work on all certificates. Please let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: Hi Michael, This is helpful. Thank you!!